# ESXI 6.7: How to only have the management interface accessable on the host machine's LAN?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, pfsense

I have an ESXI 6.7 Host and 6 Public IPs from my colocation provider. Currently one of the IPs is being used to access the web client for ESXI and another is used to access the pfSense router that is a VM on the machine. Is there a way to make it so that I can't access the Web UI from the internet but from the VPN that is setup through pfSense?

Thank You, I'm sorry if this seems too complicated.

Comment: Since the VPN assigns private IP addresses, why not use the PFSenses own firewall to block access to 443 on the the firewall except for addresses you assign to the VPN client and using the OpenVPN Interface rather than LAN or WAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any way to achieve this. If the management IP is publicly available, it's publicly available...

I bet there's a hacky way to achieve what you're trying to do, i.e. change the management IP of your ESXi host to a private IP behind your pfSense router / VPN gateway. My advice: **Don't do it!** If your pfSense VM has a problem where you need to open a console to fix it, you won't be able to do this. Why? Well, you can't connect to your ESXi host because your VPN gateway has a problem...

I think you should talk to your colocation provider, maybe they can provide a solution. Alternatively, if you access this ESXi host from a from a few IP addresses only you can make use oft the local ESXi firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly answering your question about only accessing the ESXi host through the private IPs, you *can* lock down management access to a restricted set of public IPs (your colocation partner may also be able to offer some firewalling).

See article with good instructions at https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-76DBDAC5-C212-429B-B59D-DC2FC8EFD042.html

Make sure that you add a selection of static IP addresses that you will have access to so you don’t get locked out.